# Quickbooks Custom Summary Report - QODBC default

Tags: excel, quickbooks, qodbc

I am trying to mirror the information coming out of the UI for a custom summary report; and I'm currently using the QODBC connection, and being told that there is no default filter on this report.  When I run the query without specifying an account type, I get zero values for all of my Balance Sheet accounts.  When I specify that the account type is Balance Sheet I get only Balance Sheet account values.

I don't appear to be able to override the default filter (which in the UI appears to be Income and Expense) to show ALL accounts.

I know this may not be the right forum for this, but as I am at a dead-end with the QODBC support people I thought it would be worth turning to this forum.

The query I am using is:

```
sp_report CustomSummary show Label, Amount parameters DateMacro = 'ThisYear', SummarizeRowsBy = 'Account', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month', Calendar = 'FiscalYear', ReturnRows = 'All', ReturnColumns = 'All'
```

The output from this shows zero values for BalanceSheet Accounts.  When I add the parameter AccountFilterType="BalanceSheet", I get the values for BalanceSheet accounts but not Income Statement accounts.  I am trying to get both, but seems impossible through code, but is possible through the UI.

Comment: Apparently this behaviour is dictated by the Quickbooks SDK.  However looking at the documentation for the CustomSummaryReportQuery it states that the AccountFilterType does NOT have a default value.  I'm at a dead-end with QODBC support - anyone have insight on the Quickbooks SDK and setting the AccountFilterType to "ALL" - I just want a 12 month trial balance - not sure why this is so challenging... :(

Answer (score 1):

Requesting you to refer https://community.intuit.com/articles/1197807-create-filter-and-customize-reports-in-quickbooks-desktop-for-windows

The Custom Summary Report has a default filter of All Income / Expense accounts. Only those accounts are included until you change the filter.

The SDK will follow what the UI does.

QuickBooks application (UI) does give the option to remove the default but QuickBooks SDK does not have this option available. This is a limitation of the QuickBooks SDK.

We have reported this issue to Intuit. QBWG-47383 is the QuickBooks SDK enhancement request number.